# How do I customize the location of a webform for a node type?

Tags: 7, nodes, webforms

I'm customizing a node type and need to add a webform using the [webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). How do I add the webform in a custom location without having a machine name for the webform?

In the code below for example, I want to populate body content followed by the webform:

```
<div id="content">    
    <?php print render($content['body']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['WEBFORM?!?']); ?>
</div>
```

And, yes, I know about displays and how you can change the location of a webform there - my node is too customized.

Comment: If you are using same webform, you can set default setting at content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Use the following code.

```
<?php print render($content['webform']); ?>
```

Bear in mind that if you are rendering the webform *before* the line containing `print render($content);`, you would need to hide the output of `$content['webform']` first, and then render it manually. In this case the code would be similar to the following one.

```
<?php
// This would go at the beginning of the .tpl.php file, for better readability.
// Hide the webform from rendering, because we will do it manually.
hide($content['webform']);
?>
<div class="content"><?php print render($content); ?></div>
<div class="webform"><?php print render($content['webform']); ?></div>
```

Generally speaking, I think it is a good practice to always hide elements you want to render separately, just in case at some point you move them before the `render($content)` line.